# Assert.assertTrue(current_url.contains("dashboard")); not working

Tags: selenium, maven, automation, ui-automation, serenity-bdd

I don't get what's wrong. I already imported imported Assert and I've been getting AssertionError with these following code:

[The Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2R8i.png)

[The Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWnHl.png)

[When called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOZ1Z.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, update your question with the actual code. Screenshots are not searchable. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines on good questions.

Comment: Please print `current_url` before `Assert.assertTrue` to let us know the real value of url first.

Comment: I found the issue. The issue is that the test is running fast. The current_url is getting the url of the login page. Mind pointing me to the right direction to solve this issue? thanks!

Comment: Use a wait after driver.get to allow the page to load.